# There are slimes all over my mob trap. How can I get rid of them?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My mobtrap was working perfectly a few hours ago. After relogging to the server, a massive amount of slimes spawned in my trap. They seem to be unkillable and block the canal and grinder. How can I get rid of them?

[image]

Comment: Well, the latest update "increased slime spawn rates" so that's the explanation for why it stopped work.

Comment: What texture pack is that?

Comment: For a temporary fix (getting rid of those specific slimes), you could probably walk away far enough for them to de-spawn. 9 chunks over or 144 blocks should suffice.

Comment: The pack is called "Unrealistic HD". Moving far away would only fix the problem temporarily. Also, it is SMP and moving all players away seems hard ;)

Comment: Have you tried holding all of them?

Comment: @kotekzot *holding* them? How do you plan to do that?

Comment: Dunno if this is still active, but you could always try '/kill @e[type=Slime]'

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the [Minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Slimes) they should be killed either on contact with lava (by burning) or by immersion in water (by drowning).

So unless things have changed you need to either make sure that they touch the lava or fall into the water. Then to make sure they can't jump out of the water you'll have to make it deeper (and possibly wider).

Comment: Lowering the lava will also destroy the items. I will try making them drown, though. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

In my experience with these new buggy slimes, the ones that spawn on their own can deal and take damage, while the smaller ones created from their deaths do not.

After finishing off the "real" slimes with my sword and/or bow (and collecting their slime balls), a re-log (disconnecting and reconnecting to the server) makes the bugged slimes disappear.