# Slimes do not spawn in SMP

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am having trouble getting any slimes to spawn in SMP. I have dug out 2 slime chunks with the floor at y=6.6, lit it up, and left it there for about 2 hours.

Nothing spawned.

Getting the world files, stripping all entities, and plugging them into SSP got me slimes almost immediately, in those chunks. Copying the world back to the server didn't make a difference.

On a related note, it seems that SSP will spawn **way** more mobs than SMP - I got pummeled by ~10 creepers in SSP, while in SMP, running into hostile mobs is a rare event.

Does this have to do anything with the server settings (I tested on Normal in SSP and hard in SMP), or did Mojang botch something up?

---

Proof this is a slime chunk:

[image]

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14783/how-do-i-find-slimes-in-minecraft

Comment: Re: Varying mob counts: Were SSP and SMP both at the same difficulty level?

Comment: SSP was on Normal, SMP is on Hard. Would the harder difficulty affect aggressive mobs?

Comment: @TomWijsman: both chunks are (supposedly) slime-spawning. I'll attach an image in a second.

Comment: Really? My server, i can find like 5-8 slimes per every 1 minecraft day!

Answer (score 4):

SSP normally has a higher mob spawn radius around the player. This means that there are more places for other mobs to spawn first. Because slimes spawn less than other mobs it may reach the mob cap before a slime can spawn.

You can test this by changing `view-distance=10` to a lower number in the server.properties file as this will give mobs less spaces to spawn outside of your farm.

Comment: Interesting idea. Is there a server command to kill all currently spawned mobs? That might be another way to test this theory.

Comment: Not in vanilla but I'm pretty sure most mods will.