# Slimeballs on the surface?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

While playing survival on vanilla Minecraft, I came across a shallow pool of water with 5-6 dropped slimeballs randomly in there. I've been playing Minecraft for some time, and understand that Slimes are the only mob that drop slimeballs, and that they spawn only near bedrock in specific chunks.

How on earth did I manage to find slimeballs in shallow water on the surface?

Comment: If you "understand that Slimes spawn only near bedrock in specific chunks" via a question here, you should check [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/97428/38938) instead of the currently accepted answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Slime), Slimes will spawn:

> Below level 40 in specific chunks, any light level
> Swamp biomes on levels 51 through 69, light level < 8

There's also a [section](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Slime#Spawning) containing more details of Slime spawning but the most likely answer could be the biome.

It's common for the smallest version of the slimes to be unable to get out of the water in swamps, and drown, leaving slimeballs all over the place.

Answer (score 2):

The slimes that spawned there were most likely the smallest version and had drowned. I have seen this before too.