# Can slimes spawn in the sky of a swamp?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Okay, slimes will now spawn in swamp biomes. Nowhere really said if they had any other requirements beyond low light (>8 (which if I remember correctly, is math for less than eight) )

I built an 8x8 pad 5 blocks down from the skycap in a swamp, verified with f3. It had zero light and enough space for any size to spawn (enough for all but large slimes at the very least). All I had a show up few Endermen. No slimes did.

Any thoughts or ideas? Or better yet any code miners have a great tidbit that I am missing?

I'm using vanilla Minecraft 1.6 prerelease in survival mode without cheats.

P.S. My whole goal is to not have to track down a mythical "slime chunk", but if it should come to that, I already know how, thanks though.

Comment: Why is the [windows] tag relevant to this post?

Comment: I could have sworn that there was also a vertical limit on swamp biome spawning, but the wiki doesn't back me up.  Suffice it to say that it actually has to be night (and not a new moon) instead of just dark.

Comment: According to the wiki, moon phase affects slime spawning. Not sure if it stops spawns during a certain phase, but try on different nights.

Comment: The windows tag is relevant in that, it's the OS I am running... Also it was about the only other applicable tag, as stack exchange or whoever, only lets people with a high rep to make more tags. Which is their porogative I guess...

Comment: @MBraedley oh snap... I was all over the wiki, didn't catch that it needed to be night.

Comment: @Bob What OS you're using doesn't change how Minecraft works, so the [windows] tag is not applicable. Just the [minecraft] tag is enough.

Comment: @Bob, your pad will need to be on a slime chunk even in the swamp.

Comment: @John I think that you have out dated info. There is information all over the place that supports the fact that slimes will now spawn in swamp biomes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, slimes can't spawn in the sky.

According to the decompiled Slime Entity code, slimes can spawn in swamps only between the heights of y>50 and y<70. That means a spawning pad 5 blocks below the build limit is far too high-altitude for slimes to spawn.

Comment: I knew it!  I wasn't confident enough to answer without the wiki as a source.

Comment: @MBraedley Looks like the wiki needs some new info!

Comment: Beautiful, thank you good sir. I will build accordingly. W00t codehounds!

Comment: @MBraedley Really? My [previous answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/97428/38938) actually mentioned the y-coords using the Minecraft Wiki as a source... strange

Comment: @AlvinWong: It's been edited back in.  Don't know which idiot removed it in the first place though.